# Fetch latest data on client side from server in meteor app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have created a mongoDB collection through server code in meteor:

```
//Server
Restaurants = new Mongo.Collection('restaurants')   
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    //This code only runs on the server
    Meteor.publish('restaurants', function () {
    return Restaurants.find();
  }); 
}
```

I am trying to fetch latest data on client side every time when the data changes in the database.

This is my client side code:

```
//Client
Restaurants = new Mongo.Collection('restaurants');
var myData = "";

if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Meteor.subscribe('restaurants');        
    myData = Restaurants.find();
};
```

Thanking you!

Comment: What is the question? Have you read the Meteor Guide? Seems like Tracker is what you are after. Read about it.

Comment: many thanks masterAM..works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, here's a quick revised example using your code that shows how `Tracker` works.

```
Restaurants = new Mongo.Collection('restaurants')

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe('restaurants');
  Tracker.autorun(() => {
    const restaurant = Restaurants.findOne();
    console.log(restaurant);
  });
};

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('restaurants', function restaurants() {
    return Restaurants.find();
  });

  Meteor.startup(() => {
    if (Restaurants.find().count() === 0) {
      Restaurants.insert({
        name: 'McDonalds',
      });
    }
  });
}
```

The above will first log `undefined` to your console since when `Restaurants.findOne` is first called, no restaurant data has been pushed to the client yet. By wrapping your find in a [`Tracker.autorun`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-autorun), when restaurant data is pushed to the client, your find will re-run, and the loaded restaurant will be logged to the console. So your console output will look like:

```
undefined
Object {_id: "HAJpQxfq59KPmTwDA", name: "McDonalds"}
```